# Hector localization documentation?

Tags: localization, navigation, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im trying to use the Hector localization  package. I could compile the package but still is not doing anything. Also the documentation is missing. Is there any example, documentation or helps how to make it works?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59729/hector-localization-documentation?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-04-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The author of the package [wrote](http://answers.ros.org/question/30376/hector_localization/?answer=31024#post-id-31024) on April 2nd that documentation is still missing, so it's probably still missing..

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-12**:
Did you tried to get working Hector localization package???Or somebody else got working??

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-07-08**:
Is there still no documentation on how to use the pkg? @Johannes Meyer can you tell us that?